# Facebook Graph API: Ban user function for pages doesn't work

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to have the ability to ban users in page via API. I use next request:

```
POST
/page_id/blocked
data: user=user_id
```

It was working earlier. But now is not working. Currently I get error:

"message": "(#100) Required parameter user was not provided",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,

[image: Graph API Explorer Screenshot]

The documentation still: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/blocked

How to make it work?

Comment: Any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change two things in order to make it work:

1. As the user ID came from my app, it is considered an 'app-scoped ID' (asid)
2. For blocking, the expected parameter is an array of IDs

`POST 123pageid456/blocked?asid=[123userid456]`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and filed a Facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/700023220191487/

It turns out the API does not currently support page-scoped IDs from the messenger platform. Only page IDs for the Facebook page.